# Table of variable amount of skills for users

Tags: mysql

I am converting a Microsoft Access application into a website that uses MySQL, and I need to add a table into the database that holds a list of skills for each employee. There are a total of 35 possible skills that an employee can have and each employee can have any number of them. What is the best way to represent this data?

The access implementation was to hold a row for each employee with 35 booleans columns for the skills. Is there a way to improve upon this?

Thanks.

Comment: "Improve" according to what criteria? What do you think is wrong with the current design?

Comment: I think it is inefficient to store values for columns that do not apply to the employee. I would like to store only the skills for each employee rather than all, but thinking on it, I guess it doesn't really matter since the total data usage is rather tiny.

Comment: You could improve it a lot more  if you used PostgreSQL.

Comment: No matter how small it is, use a joining table between a skill table ((skill_name varchar(), skill_code int) and the employee one.

Answer (score 0):

If you can allow for several skills per employee, using a many-to-many table table (e.g. `employees_skills`) would be the proper way to normalise the data, however there are alternatives that may suit you better for simplicity:

- use a BIGINT column (which can store up to 64 skills in binary), or
- use a [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) column (limit same as above)
- as @Vérace says in the comments, opt for PostgreSQL instead of MySQL, as it allows for arrays.

Comment: Why the downvote?  These seem like good suggestions.  (Upvoting.)